# optimize query performance for update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query :I have 350 millions records . How can I optimize the query performance so it does not takes 4 hours ?

```
DECLARE @Counter INT=0 --This causes the @@rowcount to be > 0
while @@rowcount>0
BEGIN
    SET rowcount 10000
    update r
   set Comp=t.Comp
  FROM [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Vente]r with (NOLOCK)
  inner join [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Budget] t with (index (index_Budget )) 
   on t.[Code Site]=r.[Code Site]
  and t.[Code Rayon] =substring(r.[Code Structure],1,4)
  and t.[Date Time]=convert(date,r.[Date Time])
  WHERE r.[Date Time] >= '2015-01-01 00:0:00.000'

end
SET rowcount 0
```

Comment: We have not enough info to help. Table structures, indexes, execution plans, etc helps us to help you. In general: avoid transformations on columns (like substring), SQL Server can not use indexes because of the transformation. If you have to transform the data, your database structure is simply bad. Avoid index hints, in most cases the query optimizer does it's job much better than you - especially if you have to issue a question like this. The server will ignore the nolock hint (update always lock).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimize update query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148941/optimize-update-query)

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
update r
   set Comp = t.Comp
from [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Vente]r with (NOLOCK) inner join
     [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Budget] t)
     on t.[Code Site] = r.[Code Site] and
        t.[Code Rayon] = substring(r.[Code Structure],1,4) and
        t.[Date Time] = convert(date,r.[Date Time])
where r.[Date Time] >= '2015-01-01 00:0:00.000';
```

This will be a bit challenging to optimize.  Your problem may simply be the volume of records being updated.  If so, the best approach is to re-create the table using a `select into`, truncate the table, and re-insert the rows.  This occurs because these operations are much faster than all the logging and index updating needed for an update.

But, indexes might work.  You might just try removing the `index` hint to see if SQL Server does a better job than you at optimization.  I think the best  indexes are: `vente([Date Time], [Code Site], [Code Structure])` and `Budget([Code Site], [Code Rayon], Date Time])`.