# Optimize update query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query . i am looking to update more than 350 millions of rows

```
update t   
set [OC]=r.[OC]

from [dbo].[Vente MPX] t  with (index (idocdate )) 

INNER join [dbo].tempOCMPX r with (index (idoc))  

on t.[Date Time] between r.[DATE DEBUT] and r.[DATE FIN]

--WHERE convert(date,t.[Date Time]) >= '2015-06-01'

--AND convert(date,t.[Date Time]) <= '2015-08-31'

WHERE t.[Date Time] >= '2015-01-01 00:0:00.000'

--AND r.[DATE DEBUT] <= '2015-08-31'

and t.[OC] is null
```

Here the execution plan 
[image]
[image]
This query is been executed for more for 4 days and the number of rows updated is 60 millions of rows.
How can I optimize it ?

Comment: Inner join with function call => no index usage. Query optimizer cannot use Indexes because your `ON` cluase is not sargable.

Comment: Think about making `and t.[Code Rayon] =substring(r.[Code Structure],1,4)
  and t.[Date Time]=convert(date,r.[Date Time])` sargable.

Comment: You cannot use `(NOLOCK) ` on an update. We also need to see the full execution plan, not the part you are showing, which is of little use.

Comment: You should move away from using `rowcount`; this feature is being obsoleted.  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx)

Comment: That query plan doesn't appear to match your query...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [optimize query performance for update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33079338/optimize-query-performance-for-update)

Comment: Which table is `[tempOCMPX]` and which is `[Vente MPX]`?

Comment: That NOLOCK hint on an update is deprecated (and ignored). https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3172/avoid-using-nolock-on-sql-server-update-and-delete-statements/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to update millions of records I advice you following steps:

1. Split one update statement to many short transactions. Create a loop and update 10 thousand - 1 million records at once (choose you amount). You can limit update query by dates: start from `MIN([Date Time])` and one day/week/month on every iteration and update data
2. You can drop index before updating and create it after all updates will complete. It can be faster to build index once after all than rebuild it during updates.